# Domain Property conserved after Tensoring with Transcendental Extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ is analgebraically closed field, $K$ contains $k$ and$A$ is a $k$ algebra. $p$ is a prime of A.

I want to proof that the claim that $k$ is algebraically closed, implies that $A/\mathfrak{p} \otimes_k K$ is a domain.

My attempt: $K= k(t_1,..,t_n)$ since $k$ algebraically closed, therefore $A/\mathfrak{p}_i\otimes_k K \cong (A/\mathfrak{p})(t_1,..,t_n)$. (is this correct?)

If yes, then I can observe that since $A/\mathfrak{p}_i$ is a domain, then also $ A/\mathfrak{p}(t_1,..,t_n)$.

Is this proof correct?

Here the background of my question: [How do I prove a scheme is connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87903/how-do-i-prove-a-scheme-is-connected)

Comment: $K$ is a finite extension of $k$? because it appears you are using it. Also, what is $A/\mathfrak{p}_i(t_1,..,t_n)$? usually the notation $A(t)$ is used only when $A$ is a field to mean field of rational functions.

Comment: I'm note sure. Intuitively I would guess that $A/\mathfrak{p}_i(t_1,..,t_n)$ means the field $Frac(A/\mathfrak{p})(t_1,..,t_n)$. I attatched above the original source of the problem.

Comment: Remark: The $p_i$ is a type, everywhere $p_i$ means $p$.