# Proof that a Scheme is connected

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My question refers to a step in follwing thread: [How do I prove a scheme is connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87903/how-do-i-prove-a-scheme-is-connected)

Here there is introduced a proof of following lemma:

Suppose $k$ is algebraically closed, and $K$ contains $k$, $A$ is a $k$ algebra, then the idempotents of $A\otimes_kK$ come from $A$.

In the proof he concludes that since $k$ is algebraically closed, $A/\mathfrak{p}_i\otimes_k K$ is a (integral) domain.

Why does it holds? Especially why do we need that $k$ is algebraically closed to show that $A/\mathfrak{p}_i\otimes_k K$ is a domain?

Comment: If $k$ is not algebraically closed, there are $k$-varieties which are connected but not geometrically connected. A rather easy example $\mathbb{C\otimes_R C}$ is not a domain even if $\mathbb{C}$ is a domain.

Comment: Yes, that's a good example. But what argument is used above to prove that IF $k$ is algebraically closed then $A/\mathfrak{p}_i\otimes_k K$ is a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: If $A,B$ are $k-$algebras $A,B$ are integral domains and $k$ is algebraically closed, then $A\otimes_k B$ is an integral domain.

Proof: Suppose $(\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i)(\sum_j a'_j \otimes b'_j) = 0 \in A\otimes_k B$, where we may choose $b_i,b_j$ such that $(b_i)$ and $(b'_j)$ form a $k-$linearly independent set. Replacing $A$ with the $k-$algebra generated by $a_i, a'_j$, we may assume that $A$ is finitely generated. Now for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$, we have that $(\sum_i \bar{a_i}\otimes b_i)(\sum_j \bar{a'_j} \otimes b'_j) = 0 \in A/\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k B$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed we know that $A/\mathfrak{m} \simeq A$ and in particular we have WLOG that $\sum_i \bar{a_i}\otimes b_i = \sum_i \bar{a_i} b_i = 0 \in B$. Since $(b_i)$ is $k-$linearly independent we deduce that $\bar{a_i} = 0$ for all $i$.

So we see that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, either $a_i \in \mathfrak{m}$ for all $i$ or $a'_j \in \mathfrak{m}$ for all $j$. This implies that every maximal ideal is either contained in $V(a_i)$ or $V(a'_j)$. Since $A$ is a finitely generated $k-$algebra, its closed points are dense. Since $A$ is an integral domain (in particular $\mathrm{spec}(A)$ is irreducible), this implies WLOG that $A = V(a_i)$, i.e. $a_i \in \bigcap_{\mathfrak{m}} \mathfrak{m}$. Since $A$ is Jacobson and reduced it follows that $a_i = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. One question:Do you mean that $A/\mathfrak{m} \simeq k $ of $k$ is algebraically closed? But why? $A/m$ is only finitely generated as $k$-ALGEBRA, not as $k$-module, so $A/m$ don't must be an algebraic field extension of $k$, or am I wrong? So why can you conclude that $A/\mathfrak{m} \simeq k $?

Comment: $A$ is a finitely generated k-algebra, so $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field which is also a finitely generated $k-$algebra. Zariski's lemma tells you that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $k$.